# How to capture only substrings contained in brackets?

Tags: powershell

```
$String = @'
the fox [GO Here] jumped up
HERE
Using [IMB](www.IMB.com)
Using [Xerox](www.Xerox.com)
Using [Banana](www.Banana.com)
the fox [GO Here] jumped up
'@


$String -replace "\[(.*?)\]\(", "$1"
```

The output I get is:

```
the fox  jumped up
Using (www.foxtrot.com)
Using (www.IMB.com)
Using (www.Xerox.com)
Using (www.Banana.com)
the fox  jumped up
```

What I am expecting to get is:

```
IMB
Xerox
Banana
```

According to [RexEx101](https://regex101.com/r/tZ3EKb/1), this is a valid .NET regex. My RegEx foo is not strong at all, so its likely I am at fault.

Comment: you're looking for `[regex]::Matches(  )` not `-replace`. unclear why `HERE` is part of your expected output. `[GO Here]` doesnt match your pattern and assuming it did, the the expected would be `GO Here`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon ,  I am not familiar with that `[regex]::Matches(  )`. Its looks like one of those direct .Net calls that powershell can do. Is it not possible to do this sort of operation with native powershel, `-repalce`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon , Hey I had some mistakes in my post, I edited them. I am expecting to capture only `IMB`, `Xerox`, `Banana` (I mispelt, IBM but I am rolling with it for the sake of not causing anymore confusion).  I placed `GO Here` as an example of what I dont want to capture, since its closing bracket does not have a neighbouring `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is with a direct [API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-8.0):

```bash
[regex]::Matches($String, '\[(.*?)\]\(') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Or with [`Select-String -AllMatches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-allmatches):

```bash
($String | Select-String -Pattern '\[(.*?)\]\(' -AllMatches).Matches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [positive lookbehind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions#lookbehind-assertions) `(?<=\[)` and [positive lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions#lookahead-assertions) `(?=\]\()` to match only the part that you want.

```
$String = @'
the fox [GO Here] jumped up
HERE
Using [IMB](www.IMB.com)
Using [Xerox](www.Xerox.com)
Using [Banana](www.Banana.com)
the fox [GO Here] jumped up
'@

([regex]::Matches($String, '(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\]\()')).Value
```

Output:

```
IMB
Xerox
Banana
```